# Happy 420 (games per season)

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> In a sports league, there are 20 total teams, divided into 4 divisions of 5 teams each. Over the course of a season, each team plays each of the other teams in its own division 3 times, and each of the other teams in the other divisions twice. How many games does the league have in a complete season?

I ended up getting $4(3{\binom{5}{2}}) + 2{\binom{4}{2}}({\binom{10}{2}} - 2{\binom{5}{2}})$, which evaluates to 420. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. First part is the games on own division and other parts is 2 games, you choose the two divisions and you choose one team of each division. So
$$4\cdot 3\cdot \binom{5}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1}\binom{5}{1}\cdot 2=420.$$

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an alternative approach, each team plays $4\cdot3=12$ games within its division and $15\cdot2=30$ games outside its division. This initially sounds like a total $20(12+30)=840$ games, but keep in mind that that counts each game twice (once for each team), so the correct total is $20(12+30)/2=420$.